Switch or switches in the context of trains in American English?
What I am confused about is that according to Cambridge Dictionary, the point where a train moves from one track onto the other is called "switches" in American English. The word is in plural.
Here is the definition from the above mentioned dictionary:

switches [ plural ] US (mainly UK points)
a place on a railway track where the rails (= metal bars on which the trains travel) can be moved to allow a train to change from one track to another

But in other dictionaries and in articles about trains, the word is used in its singular form e.g. train switch or just switch.
My assumption is that "switches" (pl) refers to the place where a train switches from one track to the other. When used in its singular form, "switch" refers to a device that shunts a train onto a different track.
Is my assumption incorrect? If so, please explain why the word switch in train related contexts is used both in plural and in singular and when it is correct to use the singular and the plural form.

'Headquarters' is a noun with plural form, but is invariant: it may refer to one or more than one referent/s. As a plural, 'the headquarters are in Elbon City and Dogberton' would be used, with a plural verb form. For a singular referent, there is a choice of formal or logical agreement: 'the headquarters is/are in Wallyford'. // 'A scissor' is not unknown, but is considered incorrect by some. // English has anomalous examples.

At least in the industry in the US, "the place where a train switches from one track to another" is called a "crossover", needing at least two switches; usually four to support both directions.

TLDR: The Cambridge Dictionary is incorrect.
When you have a question about American English, you should use an American dictionary, like Merriam-Webster or American Heritage Dictionary.
Here is what they say:
Merriam-Webster:

4 : a device made usually of two movable rails and necessary connections and designed to turn a locomotive or train from one track to another.

American Heritage Dictionary

2b : A device consisting of two sections of railroad track and accompanying apparatus used to transfer rolling stock from one track to another.

The Cambridge Dictionary is confused (although most of the time it handles American English quite well). Possibly somebody who speaks British English assumed that since the word points was plural, the word switch must also be plural, since they describe the same thing. This isn't the case; I've never heard it used in the plural (unless someone was talking about more than one set of points).
Looking at the American Heritage Dictionary, you can see why points is plural in British English. It has the following definition of point:

33a: A movable rail, tapered at the end, such as that used in a railroad switch.

There are several such movable rails in a switch, so using the plural points for a switch makes sense.

It would be better to include the headword: switch or switches? // This constitutes a good example of how plural form / agreement is not an inherent property of the referent. Switch = points.

The OED says switch refers to "a moveable rail or pair of rails", so there's obviously a lot of confusion about just what it applies to (either what's called a point in the UK, or a set of points). It also notes the US idiom "asleep at the switch" (singular) meaning to be off-guard, likely with a railway origin.

Thank you very much

Although the question is about American English, the railway engineers I've known insisted the correct UK term is 'switch' for the real world thing, and 'points' is model railway jargon. (though this may be another Stevenson/Brunel thing like which of 'engine' or 'locomotion' being correct)

Perhaps the term switch is more commonly used in its plural form, switches, in this context (noted in the Cambridge Dictionary as "US usually switches"). While the Cambridge Dictionary provides some insight, it is generally less comprehensive compared to the OED. In the OED, there are two examples using the plural form, and two using the singular (with one citing 'switch' in quotes), though none of the examples are from Modern English. It may also be worth reaching out to the Cambridge Dictionary for clarification.

A railway engineer or industry professional could provide confirmation and share insights on real-world scenarios.

@ermanen: As an American English speaker, I can say that among the public in general, the Cambridge Dictionary definition is wrong. And while the OED has this definition of switch, the one clear example of it that it gives is from a 1837 railroad magazine published in London. No American dictionary I can find uses the plural.
